# Return value from lambda expression

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a trouble to understand the return value from line #14. My question is about: `fn(acc), x` in one line. How is it possible to write it in a block instead? Like: `{return fn(acc), x}` ?? Of course it wouldn't work. Does any one can write it down as a block code instead of a one-line code?

```
1  const scream = str => str.toUpperCase()
2  const exclaim = str => `${str}!`
3  const repeat = str => `${str} ${str}`
4  
5  const string = 'Hello world'
6  
7  // Nested
8  // const result1= repeat(exclaim(scream(string)))
9  // console.log(result1)
10 // HELLO WORLD! HELLO WORLD!
11
12 // Instead of nesting, compose your functions into a new function
13 const compose = (...fns) => x =>
14    fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), x)
15
16 const enhance = compose(repeat, exclaim, scream)
17 const result2 = enhance(string)
18 console.log(result2)
19 // HELLO WORLD! HELLO WORLD!
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Can [anyone] write it down as a block code instead of a one-line code?" This is a pretty straightforward operation. Are you having difficulty because the `compose` function returns a function?

Comment: My question was about: `fn(acc), x` in one line. How is it possible to write it in a block instead? Like: `{return fn(acc), x}` ?? Of course it wouldn't work..

Comment: Ok, I got it! It should be `{ return fn(acc)}, x` where `x` is just another argument. It would be more clear to write it: `fns.reduceRight(((acc, fn) => fn(acc)), x)`

Answer (score 1):

The thing to note is mostly that `reduceRight` is a reverse for loop. Here is the same function with loops and regular function expressions:

```
const scream = str => str.toUpperCase()
const exclaim = str => `${str}!`
const repeat = str => `${str} ${str}`

const string = 'Hello world'

// (...fns) =>
function compose() {
  var fns = arguments;
  // x =>
  return function(x) {
    var acc = x;
    // fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) =>
    for(var i = fns.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
      var fn = fns[i];
      // fn(acc)
      acc = fn(acc);
    }
    return acc;
  }
}

const enhance = compose(repeat, exclaim, scream)
const result2 = enhance(string)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: I know what `reduceRight` is doing in this context. My question was rather about: `fn(acc), x` in one line. How is it possible to write it in a block? Like: `{return fn(acc), x}` ?? Of course it wouldn't work...

Comment: Ok, I got it! It should be `{ return fn(acc)}, x` where `x` is just another argument. It would be more clear to write it: `fns.reduceRight(((acc, fn) => fn(acc)), x)`